# MongoMapper, Padrino and Passenger - Connection Failure?

Tags: mongodb, passenger, mongomapper, padrino

I'm currently working on a Padrino project which has been working absolutely fine in developement, but after pushing it to my live environment, I'm experiencing problems. Checked the logs and the error I'm getting is:

```
[31m  ERROR[0m -[33m24/Jul/2012 11:32:53[0mMongo::ConnectionFailure - Operation failed with the following exception: #<Mongo::ConnectionFailure:0xa762528>:
```

My `database.rb` file is the standard one generated by Padrino, namely:

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', nil, :logger => logger)

case Padrino.env
  when :development then MongoMapper.database = 'licensing_development'
  when :production  then MongoMapper.database = 'licensing_production'
  when :test        then MongoMapper.database = 'licensing_test'
end
```

Everything works perfectly in the console, so I'm assuming that the problem is to do with Passenger. Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so ignore me. I forgot to set `RACK_ENV` when running the rake task that imported my data, as well as when starting the console, so there was no data in my production database.